# build category tree for categories and sub categories

Tags: magento, tree

i am trying to built category tree for the categories and sub categories in custom admin module, if possible to override the default category tree present in edit tab of product.

Below is the code which i am working, it is able to build category tree but it lack the checkbox ability. any sugestion would be appreciated

```
<?php 
$rootcatId= Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId(); 
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($rootcatId);
function  get_categories($categories) {
    $array= '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
        $count = $cat->getProductCount();
        $array .= '<li>'.
        '<a href="' . Mage::getUrl($cat->getUrlPath()). '">' . 
                  $category->getName() . "(".$count.")</a>\n";
        if($category->hasChildren()) {
            $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
             $array .=  get_categories($children);
            }
         $array .= '</li>';
    }
    return  $array . '</ul>';
}
echo  get_categories($categories); ?>
```

Comment: great work.
even i am also trying to override default category tree, but no luck.
in order to add checkbox create this whole tree in form and add checkbox with value having category id in <li>, this will solve you checkbox issue

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please clarify your question as it's bad idea to override core functionality because same function is used by different modules instead you can check functionality of these 

app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/categories.ph‌​tml app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Categories.php 

and then reflect these to your template files
```